# How to run spring batch steps sequentially (first step complete then start next step)?

Tags: spring-batch

I am using spring boot 3. I need to run spring batch. I have two steps. It seems that my both steps run concurrently.My first step data need to process first and completed first then second step because second step depends on first step data. I need to run like first step is completed, then second step started.

Here is configure:

```
        @Component
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    @Slf4j
    public class EftJob {

       private final EftProcessorStep1 batchProcessorStep1;
        private final EftWriterStep1 batchWriterStep1;

        private final EftProcessorStep2 batchProcessorStep2;
        private final EftWriterStep2 batchWriterStep2;

        private final PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;
        private final JobRepository jobRepository;

        public Job createEft(){

            String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            id = "EFT-"+id;
            return new JobBuilder(id, jobRepository)
                    .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                    .start(step1())
                   .next(step2())             
                    .build();

        }



        private Step step1(){

            return new StepBuilder("step1", jobRepository)
                    .<myrepo, myrepo> chunk(10, transactionManager)
                    .reader(new EftReaderStep1(myrepo,myrepo))
                    .processor(batchProcessorStep1)
                    .writer(batchWriterStep1)
                    .build();
        }
        private Step step2(){
          

            return new StepBuilder("step2", jobRepository)
                    .<myrepo, myrepo> chunk(10, transactionManager)
                    .reader(new EftReaderStep2(myrepo))
                    .processor(batchProcessorStep2)
                    .writer(batchWriterStep2)
                    .build();
        }

    }
```

What is wrong of my code?

Comment: The job flow you defined is correct and should run steps sequentially as you described. What makes you think or confirm that they are running concurrently?